# Error after changing name of mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF for the first time and I get an error like this:

```
Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'
```

That is becuase I changed the name. Have I missed to change this is some other code? I'm not so familiar with this type of projekt, compared with Windows Form that I used before. Which file launch the application? I have been looking for one in the solution explorer. I guess it's perhaps there the error is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it in `StartupUri` attribute of `Application` tag in `App.xaml` also.

Comment: OK, but where is this StartUpUri?

Comment: I found it! But I get a new error! In a auto generated file called App.g.cs. It's this line that has red lines below App: ControlTower.App app = new ControlTower.App();

Comment: I still get this error message: Error 1 The type name 'App' does not exist in the type 'ControlTower.ControlTower'

Comment: I made a new project and start it all over. And changed the name in StartupUri and now it's working!

Comment: Also clear the "obj" and "bin" folders after such rename, as generated files (such as App.g.cs) can still be present and cause trouble if they didn't detect the rename.

Answer (score 2):

After renaming a window project item:

- rename startup URI in App.xaml to corresponding `WindowName.xaml`;
- check `x:Class` attribute value in window XAML file, it must be match
  class name in code behind.

Comment: Yours is a completely solution and should be marked as an `Answer`. Bullet 2 of your solution is important - I had to made that change as well to make it work when I renamed the `mainwindow.xaml`.